# Bottom of Screen Positioning Mobile CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a menu that will stick at the bottom of the screen for mobile navigation so I used `position: fixed` which works on PC but not mobile.
Here's the code I used:

```
.menu_bar {
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    display:block;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

[Here's the demo](http://www.nightlifebratislava.com/demos/mobile)
And here's an Opera Mini [emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mini/)

Anyone know why I can't get it to work on a mobile? Thanks :)

EDIT: I see that most mobile browsers don't support `position: fixed`, do you know of any good alternatives? Maybe with the help of Jquery? thanks

Comment: Just looked at that demo page and the black bar remains at the bottom (iPhone 4S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think to give the table a fixed position too, but I'm not sure if that'll cause further problems so you'd have:

```
table {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px
    bottom: 75px
}

.menu_bar {
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    display:block;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

So you could still have your menu bar fixed but you may have to add an overflow: scroll; or overflow: auto; if the content is not scrolling. I would suggest reading into http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui.html to use javascript to scroll the content instead, which will probably work better.